# I am not able to set auto incrementing value with a starting value 1000 in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't find an answer. I want to add a new column to an existing table that should be an auto incrementing integer, starting with the value of `1000`.

My migration file is for now simple and obvious:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize, _, db) => {
        const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;
        const { sequelize } = db;
        await queryInterface.addColumn('class', 'id', {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            unique: true,
            defaultValue: 1000,
            autoIncrement: true,
            initialAutoIncrement: 1000
        });
    },
    down: {...}
};
```

So this adds the column to the table class, but it sets the initial value to `1` instead of `1000`.

I know it is already present in `Sequelize`. There is an option called `initialAutoIncrement`. This sets the initial `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for the table in MySQL. I even tried that in the model, but without any luck.

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Class = sequelize.define(
        'User',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.BIGINT(20),
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
            },
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(500),
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            initialAutoIncrement: 1000,
        }
    );
    return Class;
};
```

Is there a solution for this?